# one of the USB ports stopped working

Tags: usb, kernel

I'm experiencing problems with one of the USB ports on my laptop. others work all fine, but in this one, whatever I plug in I get such log in dmesg:

```
[323458.444505] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[323458.516525] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[323458.692449] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[323458.868495] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[323458.940444] usb 2-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
```

does it mean hardware fault? or is there something I can try?